# Getting page error 404 while calling Mage::getStoreConfig with current storeId

Tags: magento-1.9, system-config, multi-website, system-configuration

Using Magento 1.9.3 `Mage::getStoreConfig` is redirecting magento admin to 404 page instead of retrieving the store field value.

---

### In controller

```
$store = $this->getRequest()->getParam('website');

if (!$store) { 
    $storeID = 1; //use default store if none was given 
} else {
    $storeID = Mage::app()->getWebsite($store)->getId();
}

Mage::helper('setstartordernumber')->getOrderNumber($storeID)
```

---

### In helper

```
class Aschroder_SetStartOrderNumber_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    public function getOrderNumber($iStoreId=null) {
        return Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/setstartordernumber/order',$iStoreId);
    }
}
```

What could the code be missing? Any idea?

**Update:**

This issue arise only when calling `Mage::getStoreConfig` from Helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Mage::getStoreConfig` causing magento return 404 with no error logs or exceptions I decided to create a custom function to get store configuration base on path and scope Id (store id in my case).

```
class Aschroder_SetStartOrderNumber_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

    // some code

    public function getStoreConfig($path, $scopeId) {
        $configs = Mage::getModel('core/config_data')->getCollection();
        $configs->getSelect()->where('path=?', $path);
        $configs->getSelect()->where('scope_id=?', $scopeId);
        foreach ($configs as $val) {
            return $val->getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below Code

```
$store = Mage::app()->getStore(); // store info
$configValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName', $store);
```

Comment: I need current store config field value

Comment: i HAVE updated please check

Comment: None of them will work for me. I'm trying to get field info from system -> configuration -> sales

Comment: i Have Updated my code please check once.

Comment: This won't either, because I want to pass specific website name in the url